# Django-React not staying logged in

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

I have a React JS - Django site and I implemented the login functionality. But I have seen that the user does not stay logged in even though it authenticates and moves to the home page after log in. I tried displaying the username once it navigates to the home page and it returns empty.

Views.py

```
class Login(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        # Authenticate user
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            # If authentication succeeds, log in the user
            login(request, user)
            return JsonResponse({"message": "Login successful"})
        else:
            # If authentication fails, return error response
            return JsonResponse({"error": "Invalid username or password"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Login.js

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/login/", {
        method: 'POST',
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
      });
      
      const data = await response.json();

      if (response.ok && data.message === "Login successful") {
        // Redirect to the home page upon successful login
        navigate('/');
      } else {
        // Set error state with the error message
        setError(data.error);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle network or server errors
      setError("An error occurred during login. Please try again later.");
    }
```

I have the necessary session middleware in my settings.py as well.

I tried adding middleware to settings.py and session cookie age but it didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

more information on how you application works will be effective in providing a better solution.
Apart from that If you application works based on token, and you react application is a seperate app, then you will have to store your token as a state and pass if on for each request.
From your above JS code, you have not used the data received after the authentication to save or store it.

Comment: Consider I just want a basic React Js- Django application with login. I didnt think of storing the token since I assumed Django stores the session cookies automatically. I will try that, thank you!